# Full path is not saved to media when I implement django-tenants in my django project

Tags: python, django, postgresql, multi-tenant, django-multitenant

I am implementing multitenant in a django project with PostgreSQL for this I implemented a library called django-tenants but I have a small problem what I wanted was to save the media files for each scheme in a folder with the same name of the scheme for it in the official documentation It told me that I had to put this configuration in my settings.py.

```
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'django_tenants.files.storage.TenantFileSystemStorage

MULTITENANT_RELATIVE_MEDIA_ROOT = ""
```

To be able to save a folder of the media of my models for each scheme, when I test my model

```
class Product(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Name')
     image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product/%Y/%m/%d', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Image')
```

Actually saving in the correct folder is called schema/product/2023/08/30/imagen.png but when I consult the path in the database it only saves me product/2023/08/30/imagen.png how do I get it to be save the schematic also in the path?

I made this code to solve the problem

```
def image_upload_path(base_path):
     def upload_path(instance, filename):
         tenant = connection.get_tenant()
         current_date = datetime.now()
         return f"{tenant.schema_name}/{base_path}/{current_date.year}/{current_date.month}/{current_date.day}/{filename}"

     return upload_path

image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_path('product'), null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Image')
```

It works but I would like to make it more general to avoid repeating code that affects all fields that are image or file